# Crash report not generated for Private channel apps?

Tags: android, crash-reports

I am quite new to the android app publishing on private channel. While testing an app which is published to the private channel in my organization, it crashed. I am wondering why the crash is not reported in the developer console. When the crash happened on the nexus 9 tablet, the app exited to the desktop instead of showing the dialog with two options 1. Report 2. Ok.

So my questions are:
1. Are there any settings need to be enabled to report the crashes/ANRs to the play store while publishing the app in private channel?

2. Are there any tablet settings those needs enabled?
3. Are there any developer console settings those need to be enabled?
4. Does the native code crashes(segmentation fault, NPE etc) are recorded/reported through this mechanism as well?

Any input on this is highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot
Santosh

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `android.permission.INTERNET` set up in your `AndroidManifest`. Crash reports are only reported when a user explicitly sends a crash report (which may only be a very small proportion of the overall crashes).

FYI: There are third party crash reporting solutions available. One well known one is [Crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com/), which does not require a Play Store presence.